# Unable to add swipe recognizer to SKScene in Swift playground?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-playground, skscene

Ok, Im still a little new to how swift playgrounds work but I am trying to add a swipe gesture recognizer in Swift 3 to my swift playground. Following this http://www.spritekitlessons.com/gesture-recognizer-with-sprite-kit-and-swift/ I now have:

```
func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("swiped right")
}

func swipedLeft(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("swiped left")
}

func swipedUp(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("swiped up")
}

func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("swiped down")
}

let degree = CGFloat(M_PI_2) / 90


class GameScene: SKScene {
    var selectedNode: SKNode?
    var shakeAction: SKAction?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        /* Setup your scene here */

        let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("swipedRight:")))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


        let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("swipedLeft:")))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)


        let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("swipedUp:")))
        swipeUp.direction = .up
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)


        let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("swipedDown:")))
        swipeDown.direction = .down
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    }

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 600) //view size
let view = SKView(frame: frame)

let scene = GameScene(size: frame.size)
view.presentScene(scene)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

This compiles, however when I swipe I get an unrecognized selector error even though I did include the functions with the selector: 
[image]

I have tried placing the functions within the class as well. How can I add a swipe recognizer to a Swift playground SKScene?

Answer (score 1):

You have selectors passed as strings, something is definitely wrong with them as said in error log

Try to use new selector syntax - `#selector(methodName)`.

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /* Swift 3 */

        let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleSwipe))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

    }

    func handleSwipe() {
        print("Swiped!")
    }
}
```

Using strings for selectors has been **deprecated**.
Using new selector syntax if the `methodName()` method doesn't exist, you'll get a compile error – your app won't crash because of "unrecognized selector".